# Flutter - Programmatically change the mouse cursor without rebuilding the widget. Setting cursor in a RenderBox?

Tags: flutter, mouse, renderbox

The most common use to change the cursor is through `MouseRegion` and `setState`. Example:

```dart
MouseRegion(cursor: _myCursor);

setState(() {
  if(...) {
    _myCursor = SystemMouseCursors.copy;
  } else {
    _myCursor = SystemMouseCursors.move;
  }
});
```

Is there a way to make this change without rebuilding the `Widget`? The `CustomPaint`, for example, accepts a `Listening` that, when triggered, will only notify a new repaint without rebuild.

Maybe if it were possible to set the mouse cursor inside a `RenderBox`. I could create one replicating the behavior of `CustomPaint` using a `Listening` and `markNeedsPaint` method.

Has anyone already configured the cursor inside the `RenderBox`?

Comment: `RenderMouseRegion` had a public setter for its `cursor` property - try it

Comment: Thanks, @pskink. The secret is to implement `MouseTrackerAnnotation`.

Answer (score 0):

Studying `RenderMouseRegion`, I figure out that your custom `RenderBox` needs to implement `MouseTrackerAnnotation` to change the cursor. The `hitTest` must return `TRUE`.

Comment: can you please provide a full example? I'm also trying to achieve this.